# Libtool installation problems

Tags: javascript, linux, makefile, configure

```
$ autoreconf -fi
src/Makefile.am:43: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:43: src/Makefile.am:43: The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' 
src/Makefile.am:43: to `configure.ac' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf'
again. autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I changed the `configure.ac` as it said,
but when I turned to use `./configure`, there were still a few errors:

```
./configure: line 19537: syntax error near unexpected token `[disable-fast-install'
./configure: line 19537: `LT_INIT#([disable-fast-install)]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **reinstall** it in order to fix the error so follow these steps :

1] Remove current libtool if installed: `sudo apt-get purge libtool`

2] Download it from official website https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/

3] Untar it: `tar -xzvf "name of the tar_file"`

4] Enter folder and type: `./configure && make`

5] Install it: `sudo make install`

And you are done, error should be fixed !

Comment: Thanks.It is helpful.